# 3 equations with 3 unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The Little Town Arts Center charges $\$23$ for adults, $\$12$ for senior citizens, and $\$8$ for children under 12 for their live performances on Sunday afternoon. This past Sunday, the paid revenue was $\$11,049$ for $784$ tickets sold. There were $43$ more children than adults. How many children attended?

Answer (score 1):

Let adults be $x$ senior citizens be $y$ and children be $z$ .

We have

$x+y+z = 784$

$23x+12y+8z = 11049$

$z = 43+x $

Solve using substitution you will get $\#children = z =302$